# TypeError while trying to append an integer to a queue

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I get an error while trying to append an integer to my queue.

```
from _collections import deque
q = deque
q.appendleft(5) 
q.appendleft(6)
q.appendleft(12)
print(q.pop())
print(q.pop())
print(q.pop())
```

I expected to get the values I appended in the reverse order but got a TypeError Instead.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'appendleft' for 'collections.deque' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

How else am I supposed to use a queue?

Answer (score 3):

```py
q = deque()
```

You missed the parentheses.